# Why does Pandas convert my DataFrame into a DataFrame and a Series inside a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
arms_bayes_list = pandas.DataFrame(
            {'arms': pandas.Series(arms_bayes), 'priori_mean': pandas.Series(arm_priori_mean_vectorized(arms_bayes)),
             'variance_square': pandas.Series(arm_variance_square_vectorized(arms_bayes)),
             'posterior_mean': pandas.Series(arm_posterior_mean_vectorized(arms_bayes)),
             'posterior_variance_square': pandas.Series(arm_posterior_variance_square_vectorized(arms_bayes)),
             'empirical_mean': pandas.Series(arm_empirical_mean_vectorized(arms_bayes)),
             'mean': pandas.Series(arm_mean_vectorized(arms_bayes)),
             'priori_variance_square': pandas.Series(arm_variance_square_vectorized(arms_bayes))})

        optimal_mean_bayes = numpy.amax(arms_bayes_list[["mean"]])
        print(type(arms_bayes_list))
         # This gives a datatype <class'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
        for round_no in range(int(no_of_rounds)):
            print(type(arms_bayes_list))
            # This gives a datatype <class'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'><class      'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Iterating over the data frame I get the error that Series has no attribute called 'itertuples'/ 'iterrow' so I really can't iterate over the DataFrame.

Well, this is rather mysterious to me. For some reason the type of the DataFrame is different inside the for loop than what it is outside the for loop. I don't think I've made any mistakes but I another set of eyes would definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try printing `arms_bayes_list.__class__` instead of `arms_bayes_list`

replace your line of `print(type(arms_bayes_list))` to this print(arms_bayes_list.**class**)
Took the liberty of doing it for you.

```
arms_bayes_list = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'arms': pandas.Series(arms_bayes), 
     'priori_mean': pandas.Series(arm_priori_mean_vectorized(arms_bayes)),
     'variance_square': pandas.Series(arm_variance_square_vectorized(arms_bayes)),
     'posterior_mean': pandas.Series(arm_posterior_mean_vectorized(arms_bayes)),
     'posterior_variance_square': pandas.Series(arm_posterior_variance_square_vectorized(arms_bayes)),
     'empirical_mean': pandas.Series(arm_empirical_mean_vectorized(arms_bayes)),
     'mean': pandas.Series(arm_mean_vectorized(arms_bayes)),
     'priori_variance_square': pandas.Series(arm_variance_square_vectorized(arms_bayes))
    })

optimal_mean_bayes = numpy.amax(arms_bayes_list[["mean"]])

for round_no in range(int(no_of_rounds)):
    print(arms_bayes_list.__class__)
    # ... rest of the code
```

Comment: Well this works but that was not the intention I had for the code. I want to use itertuples to iterate through all the dataframe however for some reasons it iterates over the other ‘Series’ as well so I was looking for a method to extract the dataframe from arms_bayes_list

Comment: You could try the` iterrows()` method, it  returns an iterator yielding index and row data for each row.  Or the `apply()` as I am not exactly sure of what you are trying to do. But do try them, and give me a response.

Comment: Well now I am getting the error object 'Series' has no attributes iterrows